# Div with image scales with odd pixels?

Tags: css, grid, scale

I try to make a responsive grid with square images, but the first square image needs to be twice as big as the others. I can do this with jQuery, but i want to fix it with css if its possible.

**Grid**
Here is an example of the grid. The red squares are divs with an image inside:

[image]

**The way i thought it would work**

I thought it would be simple:
If every div has a width of 20%, the :first-item should have 40%. The height of all the divs are auto because all images are 500 x 500 px. So it would be logical that the height scales twice to.

To my suprise it's not working on all screen sizes. On some screensizes the first div is 1 pixel to big. Example: When the first image has a height of 533px, the images next to the first image has a height of 266 px. That means that the first image is 1 pixel to big (266 x 2 = 532). So the third row with images goes wrong.

Here's an example of the grid online: http://bit.ly/LKdKMj Scale the browser to a lower size and you can see the behavior of the images.

Does anybody know why this won't work?

I added the HTML and CSS below.

Many thanks,

Wnd

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">

    <header id="header">
    </header>

    <nav id="leftmenu">
    </nav>

    <section id="content">
            <article class="item">
                <img src="img/item.jpg" alt=""/>
            </article>
            <article class="item">
                <img src="img/item.jpg" alt=""/>
            </article>
            <article class="item">
                <img src="img/item.jpg" alt=""/>
            </article>
            <article class="item">
                <img src="img/item.jpg" alt=""/>
            </article>
            <article class="item">
                <img src="img/item.jpg" alt=""/>
            </article>
            <article class="item">
                <img src="img/item.jpg" alt=""/>
            </article>
            <article class="item">
                <img src="img/item.jpg" alt=""/>
            </article>
            <article class="item">
                <img src="img/item.jpg" alt=""/>
            </article>
            <article class="item">
                <img src="img/item.jpg" alt=""/>
            </article>
            <article class="item">
                <img src="img/item.jpg" alt=""/>
            </article>
            <article class="item">
                <img src="img/item.jpg" alt=""/>
            </article>
            <article class="item">
                <img src="img/item.jpg" alt=""/>
            </article>
            <article class="item">
                <img src="img/item.jpg" alt=""/>
            </article>
    </section>

</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
html, body{margin: 0; padding: 0;}

#header{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background: #222;
}

#leftmenu{
    height: 1000px;
    width: 20%;
    float: left;
    background: #505050;
}

#content{
    width: 80%;
    float: left;
}
#content .item{
    float: left;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
#content .item img{
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    height: auto;
}

/*GRID*/

@media only screen and (max-width: 2700px) {

  #content .item:first-child{width: 25%;}
  #content .item{width: 12.5%;}

}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1920px) {

  #content .item:first-child{width: 40%;}
  #content .item{width: 20%;}

}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1400px) {

  #content .item:first-child{width: 50%;}
  #content .item{width: 25%;}

}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) {

  #content .item:first-child{width: 66.66666%;}
  #content .item{width: 33.33333%;}

}

@media only screen and (max-width: 720px) {

  #content .item:first-child{width: 66.66666%;}
  #content .item{width: 33.33333%;}

}

@media only screen and (max-width: 520px) {

  #content .item, #content .item:first-child{width: 50%;}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can never be sure with percentages.
i believe one solution is to never go for 100%. instead use something like:
`width:25%-2px` for example,

or aim for a smaller percentage(not 100% but 99%)
so your divs should be for example: 39.5%+19.5%+19.5%+19.5% instead of 40%+20%+20%+20% 
(the numbers are just for demonstration and do not apply to your specific code)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That trick doesn't work for me. It means that the images doesn't fill the screen, so there's always a space visible. Beside that, i tried your solution but it still doesn't scale the right way. I think it has to deal with odd and even pixels or something. Example of your solution: [link]http://bit.ly/1cYrs4b[/link]

Comment: well you are right , that is an interesting problem then and id like to see the answer!

Comment: Me too, i hope there is!

Answer (score 0):

You can make the article tags square by using padding-bottom with the same percentage as width. that will keep them square at all times.

```
#content .item{
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    margin: 0px;
    width: 40%;
    padding-bottom: 40%;
}
```

you then can place the image inside with some absolute positioning

```
#content .item img{
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

check this fiddle. I replaced the empty image tags with placeholders for a better visualisation.

http://jsfiddle.net/Haroldchen/LWR3X/

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I didn't use that way to create square divs before. So, thanks for that ;) But in this case it acts exactly the same as my example above. I've put your example online: [link]http://bit.ly/1g3MsOP[/link]

Comment: I just noticed it myself as I was testing around a bit. seems there are a some subpixel issues. there might be no 'non-js' way around that though.